# Android: Simpify many classes and xml

Tags: android, xml, class

Edit: I cannot get this to work correctly. Probably because I have no idea what I am doing. Anyways, here's my code. If anyone could help, I'd be very grateful: I needs to get it to display the battery mood image for the corresponding mod...

Themes:

```
package com.cydeon.plasmamodz;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Themes extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.themes);
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.hide();
    Button Plus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button Blue = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    Plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Themes.this, Bmod.class);
            i.putExtra("drawableResource", R.drawable.blue);
            Themes.this.startActivity(i);

        }
    });

    Blue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent a = new Intent(Themes.this, Bmod.class);
            a.putExtra("drawableResource1", R.drawable.plus);
            Themes.this.startActivity(a);

        }
    });


}

}
```

Bmods:

```
package com.cydeon.plasmamodz;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Bmod extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.battery);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    int drawableResource = i.getIntExtra("drawableResource", R.drawable.blue);
    ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv1);
    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.blue);

    Intent a = getIntent();
    int drawableResource1 = a.getIntExtra("drawableResource1", R.drawable.plus);
    ImageView img1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv1);
    img1.setImageResource(R.drawable.plus);
}



}
```

battery(xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout                          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bInstall"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="Install" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bReturn"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="Return" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="800dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: what exactly is your question?

Answer (score 3):

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, BaseClassForMod);
i.putExtra("drawableResource", R.drawable.this_mod_drawable);
startActivity(i);
```

Then in that Activity's onCreate():

```
Intent i = getIntent();
int drawableResource = i.getIntExtra("drawableResource", R.drawable.default);
//Get a reference to your ImageView...
imageView.setImageResource(drawableResource);
```

Don't trust this code to compile, but that's the general idea. Use the same Activity for all of them, pass along the proper resource ID in the intent (e.g. for mod1, send the drawable ID for mod1), then in the activity, check for that resource ID and set it programmatically.

Comment: I understand how to do this, but I'm a little confused. How would I pass along the proper resource ID in the intent? Like how would I send the drawable ID for my first mod(mod1).

Comment: You pass `R.drawable.mod1` instead of where I have `R.drawable.this_mod_drawable`. It's just an integer value.

Comment: Thanks. One more question. How would I load this image from a url instead of a drawable?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need 50 classes and 50 xml layouts if every one of them does the same thing. Make one activity and one layout. When the user selects something, pass an id of some kind as an Intent extra to the second activity so it can load whatever item is appropriate. I don't know how your data is modeled, but there should be a way to uniquely identify each option (and if there isn't, you should implement one).

Your first activity also doesn't need a button for each item. Use a ListView and an Adapter, and then you just need to provide a layout for one row.

Answer (score 1):

make a single activity only. Inside of it get a reference to your image:

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.yourImgId);
```

Then set the picture to whichever one you want like:

```
iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.battery_img_1);
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it, although I'm still a little confused on how to do this. If you can, can you explain a bit more? Maybe give an example. You don't have to though. What I really want to know is how to do this with the url for an image.